# Missing Values per participant in a repeated measures design using SPSS

Tags: spss, missing-data

I've got a dataset with repeated measures that looks roughly like this:

```
ID  v1  v2  v3  v4
1    3   4   2  NA
1    2  NA   6  7
2    4   3   6  4
2    NA  2   7  9
.    .   .   .  .
n    .   .   .  .
```

What I want to know is how many NAs are there for each participants over the variables v1 - v4 (e.g. participant 1 is missing 2 of 8 responses)? 
Missing Values are always displayed per Variable not per participant so how do I do this?  Maybe there is a way using the AGGREGATE command with ID as BREAK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNT to count the missing values as a new variable and then aggregate by the Id or split files by I'd and freq.